# Hi, I am using RestFull webservices with SpringMvc, I am getting bellow exception while starting apache server.Please help me to resolve this

Tags: spring-mvc

> Error description
>   :org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0':
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map
>   'xyz' bean method  public
>   v1.com.practiceproject.response.ResponseObject
>   v1.com.practiceproject.service.xyz.getSelectedProduct(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception to
>   {[/person/person],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}:
>   There is already 'personService' bean method public
>   v1.com.practiceproject.response.ResponseObject
>   v1.com.practiceproject.service.PersonService.getSelectedProduct(java.lang.String)
>   throws java.lang.Exception mapped.    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5291)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map
>   'xyz' bean method  public
>   v1.com.practiceproject.response.ResponseObject
>   v1.com.practiceproject.service.xyz.getSelectedProduct(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.Exception to
>   {[/person/person],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[application/json],custom=[]}:
>   There is already 'personService' bean method public
>   v1.com.practiceproject.response.ResponseObject
>   v1.com.practiceproject.service.PersonService.getSelectedProduct(java.lang.String)
>   throws java.lang.Exception mapped.    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.registerHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:176)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:148)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:109)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:89)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:163)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
>     ... 21 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your Stack trace shows you have "Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'xyz' bean method public" "There is already 'personService' bean method" as i guess your two @RequestMapping urls are same.